# UITableViewController and background color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to show a login window items including userid/password and a few other cells info as tableView's cell in center of my first login screen in my app.

I use my appDelegate to present my TableViewController. Since I wanted to place tableView in center of whole screen and make it smaller than screen size,  I changed the size of tableview  in viewDidAppear() method by using "self.tableView.frame = smallerRect;" everything is fine but the color/contrast difference between the tableView region and the rest of the screen it is kinda ugly. Do you know what I have to do to make background color of tableView be the same as bg color of whole screen, that pretend the tableView covers entire screen but with smaller cell's widths?

Thanks,
Kam 
[image]

Comment: self.tableView.backgroundColor = ?

Comment: No it didn't work it just paints the left and right parts of each cell

Comment: Can you include a screenshot, this is pretty hard to visualise

Comment: how can I upload a file?

Comment: Edit your question, click add image and select your image.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: as you see in the screenshot around the tableView there is a white margins, how can I make it the same as tableView's bg color?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8892/discussion-between-kam-and-jrturton)

Answer (score 3):

UITableView has a property, backgroundView.

Made a UIView, set its backgroundColor to whatever I wanted, and then set the tableView's backgroundView property to that view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this with a TableViewController.  What you need is a ViewController with a TableView added to it.  Make sure to set the delegate and datasource to the VC class and include the required delegate and datasource methods and you should be good to go.  About the only time I use a TableViewController versus a VC with a TV added is when I want to use a Static Cell TableView or am providing a view for a PopOverController In those cases a TVC is needed, all the other times you get much more freedom and flexibility by using a VC with a TV.

Comment: I tried that approach as well and it ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?  I have an example that does just what you are wanting (shows a login screen in the same view that holds the TV).  I use the time it takes a user to login to load 6000 records from a  web service.  It is almost always done when the user has finished typing in credentials and so the user sees the loading indicator little if any amount of time.

Comment: NO I don't use a nib file. But how can you give me that sample

Comment: May I check the code? I didn't get any answer to fix the problem yet.

Answer (score -1):

In your appDelegate, try setting self.window.backgroundColor to the color similar to your tableview's background color.

Comment: that I tried but the tableView's background color is not one of the predefined like grayColor/lightgrayColor/... I tried to make something close to it I couldn't match it. The question is how I can change the background color of smaller(tableView)? Thanks